# Service worker fetch event handleR with spring MVC

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am trying a make a spring MVC app with offline features.Everything is working fine except the fetch handler.

### Problem:

I am able to successfully register my service worker but when it comes to fetch handler it ain't working.

### Things I tried:

Used debugger above and below the fetch handler.I found out that it is never being called. I am unable to find out the reason behind this strange behaviour.

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    console.log('The service worker is being installed.');  
    event.waitUntil(precache());
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    alert("Hi");  
});
```

Comment: Make sure the service worker is on the root of your site. with spring MVC added the resource you tend to have it under some path.

Answer (score 0):

["a service worker registration ties the provided script URL to a scope, which is subsequently used for navigation matching."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/register)

What you're probably doing is 
`navigator.serviceWorker.register( '{SOME_RESOURCE_PATH}/service-worker.js')` or even setting `scope: './'`. The problem with this is that is it will make your fetch only trigger on `https://foo.bar/{SOME_RESOURCE_PATH}/`. Meaning that you will need to set the sw onto the root of your site to remove the resource path being needed. What you'll need to do is change the config to put the sw on the root of the site.

ex. of what you can do in the `mvc-config.xml`

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="classpath:/PATH_TO_SW/"/>
```

then registering the sw would look like

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register( '/service-worker.js')
```

Comment: Never knew this will be the issue!! Thanks, I will try this and let you know if it works.